# Siklu etherhaul-1200f snmpset reebot

Tags: snmp, mib

Is there anyway to reboot the radio the above radio trough snmpset ?
What else can I do with snmpset and where do I get the mibs ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you check vendor web site for MIB files? It is common practice for the equipment vendors to include CD with documentation, firmware updates and MIBs.

Comment: I did nothing there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the target MIB file for you. You can download it at:  http://netmechanica.com/MIBs/SIKLU-MIB.mib

However, according to MIB file definitions the device does not support remote reboot.

I was able to compile the MIB file using **NetDecision MIB Manager**.
[image: Silku MIB file compiled with NetDecision MIB Manager]